# Print unique values from an array column as a comma-separated string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unique, implode, array-column

I want to print all unique `Department` values from a multidimensional array as a comma-separated string, but not all rows have a `Department` value.

The boiled down version of my array looks like this:

```
$employee = [
    ["employee_id" => 1, "Department" => "Tech"],
    ["employee_id" => 2, "Department" => "Tech"],
    ["employee_id" => 3],
    ["employee_id" => 4, "Department" => "Tech"],
    ["employee_id" => 5],
    ["employee_id" => 6, "Department" => "Crm"],
    ["employee_id" => 7],
    ["employee_id" => 8, "Department" => "Crm"],
    ["employee_id" => 9, "Department" => "Crm"],
    ["employee_id" => 10],
    ["employee_id" => 11, "Department" => "Crm"],
    ["employee_id" => 12, "Department" => "Crm"]
];
```

I tried with:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($employee); $i++) {
    print_r(array_unique($employee[$i]['Department']));
}
```

But I generate Warnings when I try to access a non-existent Department value.

Expected output:

```
Tech,Crm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

echo implode(",",array_unique(array_column($employee,'Department')));
```

Use `array_column` to filter values of `Department` column and use `array_unique()` to have unique values of `Department`. Now, just `implode()` them based on `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid calling `array_unique()` after `array_column()` by repeating its second parameter as its third parameter.  PHP does no allow duplicate kays on the same level as an array.  When a repeated Department is encountered, the old value is replaced with its newer, identical value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qAo3F))

```
echo implode(',', array_column($employee, 'Department', 'Department'));
// Tech,Crm
```